# Centering JQuery popup horizontally with max-width and min-widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, center

what i have seen so far, is that centering a popup horizontally and vertically is with set widths, ie:

```
width:200px; 
height:200px;
left:50%;
top: 50%;
position:fixed;
```

but I am trying to add max and min widths to the popup because I have some that are wider and some that are shorter but I want to control the width to not pass a certain width.

```
.web_dialog
{
display: none;
position: fixed;
min-width: 360px;
min-height: 180px;
max-width: 880px;
max-height: 480px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding:10px;
z-index: 102;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 10pt;
z-index:1001;
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .333); 
}
```

now when I do this yes the popup grows but to the right so it makes it seem like its uncentered.  Any help clearing this up for me I would really appreciate it.  I just went through deleting all my ajax toolkit popups to replace for this simple jquery one and I hope to make it work cause there were alot of pages I had to change.. :S

Comment: do you want pure css based solution or jQuary will do?

Comment: i dont know about JQuary but JQuery will do ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ejijoj/2)

**Source Code**
http://jsbin.com/ejijoj/2/edit

Comment: this seems ok, but it doesn't look really centered horizontally, when I put alot of text into it just to try, it leaves more space on the left than the right.

Comment: i tweeked my popup css and took out the min values and somehow that got it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the width and height, just add `margin-left: -width/2` and `margin-top: -height/2`. But since you do not know the value, you first need to capture it and then apply the CSS rule:

```
$(function(){
  $dialog = $(".web_dialog");
  var w = $dialog.width();
  var h = $dialog.height();

  $dialog.css({'margin-left' : -w/2, 'margin-top' : -h/2});
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kenPN/

Comment: I tried that but take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kenPN/5/ you had width and height set to 200px and not using just min and max width and heights, when I took the set out it moved the popup out of the centering.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind wrapping the .web-dialogue box in a container element, you can get it to work this way: http://dabblet.com/gist/3738494, using 'display: inline-block', 'vertical-alignment' and 'text-align: center'.

Read more on how I centered the element: http://www.css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: this works, except that the container blocks the controls on the page.  I can't click on anything unless i remove the position:fixed

Comment: I would suggest using 'pointer-events: none' on the container and 'auto' on the pop-up, but the support is underwhelming https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events :/